# Normal distribution in linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, normality-assumption, definition

There are some references like [this](https://scholarworks.umass.edu/pare/vol18/iss1/11/) that says in linear regression, this is not necessary for variables to have normal distribution.
but I read some books that say otherwise:

Joseph Hilbe in a book called "Modeling Count Data" on page 3 states that

> The traditional linear regression model is based on the normal or Gaussian probability distribution.

A book entitled "Geographically Weighted Regression" authored by Fotheringham, Brunsdon and Charlton on page 188 says:

> The basic linear regression model assumes a Gaussian distribution for the dependent variable, which has a number of properties: for example, it is symmetrical about some mean value and it admits values anywhere in the interval $(-\infty,\infty). $

Now I am just really confused!

Comment: Several pages on this site discuss the assumptions underlying linear regression: [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16381/28500), [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148803/28500), [this pge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/395011/28500), and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/86835/28500) among others. Regression is sometimes taught from the perspective of the correlation of normally distributed variables, but there's no _requirement_ for normality even in the error distribution (although that can simplify inference).